# Setup a email feedback loop header with PHP for spam complaints (gmail)

Tags: php, email, gmail, spam, feedback-loop

I'm planning to send mass emails to gmail addresses via PHP mail function. To track email spam complaints i'm trying to setup a feedback loop with PHP but i'm not receiving any response from gmail. I've set header to PHP mail in the following format for PHP mail function:

```
$headers .= "Feedback-ID: CampaginABC:Customer123:CustomID:MyUniqueSenderID";
```

What are the best ways to track spam and bounce complaint Data? 
Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Gmail Feedback Loop Source:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6254652?hl=en&ref_topic=7279058

Answer (score 1):

Feedback-ID header needs to be included in DKIM-Signature. If you are sending emails with Postfix and doing DKIM signing with OpenDKIM then you can configure it as follows :

> add "SignHeaders Feedback-ID" to /etc/opendkim.conf

and reload opendkim,postfix

> /etc/init.d/opendkim reload
>
> /etc/init.d/postfix reload

Comment: If we are using custom dkim sign from our mail client so what should we do